# PHP OO retry logic implementation and passing dynamic method and args

Tags: php

My first question here.

The question is similar to this one: [PHP: Retrying a query a set number of times or until success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712161/php-retrying-a-query-a-set-number-of-times-or-until-success)

Try till success in OO way.
Here example what i'm trying to do:

```
class Creatives {

    public function run() {
        $auth_token='mypassword';
        $id=123123;
        $this->retry_till_success ( $this->getCreatives, array($auth_token, $id) );
        print $this->creatives; 
    }

    public function getCreatives($auth_token, $id) {
        $this->creatives = $this->campagin->get($auth_token, $id);      
    }

    private function retry_till_success($method, $args) {
        do {
            $try_again = false;
            try {
                /* how to call the method with */
                /* call user method with params pass */
                /* do until success */
            } catch (SoapFault $fault) {
                if($fault->faultstring== 'couldnt connect to host')
                    $try_again=true;
            }
        } while ($try_again);
    }
}
```

i read about call_user_func, but don't know if i could use it inside the class,
I need to make 99.9% success rate in my calls, any suggestion to achieve this will be great.
thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way would be to extend SoapClient and add the retry in the __call method.

```
class LocalSoapClient extends SoapClient
{

  public function __call($function_name, $arguments)
  {
    $result = false;
    $max_retries = 5;
    $retry_count = 0;

    while(! $result && $retry_count < $max_retries)
    {
      try
      {
        $result = parent::__call($function_name, $arguments);
      }
      catch(SoapFault $fault)
      {
        if($fault->faultstring != 'Could not connect to host')
        {
          throw $fault;
        }
      }
      sleep(1);
      $retry_count ++;
    }
    if($retry_count == $max_retries)
    {
      throw new SoapFault('Could not connect to host after 5 attempts');
    }
    return $result;
  }
}
```

then when you instantiate your soap client use `new LocalSoapClient()` instead of `new SoapClient()`

Answer (score 1):

[`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) is great for this:

```
$result = call_user_func_array( array($this, $method), $args );
```

The first argument is the callback [pseudo-type](http://uk.php.net/callback), and the second is an array of parameters which will be passed to the function/method as individual arguments.

As a side note, you might want to look at throttling your retries (e.g. have a sleep time which doubles every time it fails up to a set limit). If the connection to the host is down there may not be much point in retrying as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
private function retry_till_success($method, $args) {

...

$this->$method($args[0], $args[1]);
```

}

You could also use ReflectionClass/ReflectionMethod and call InvokeArgs() for a variable number of args

http://nz.php.net/oop5.reflection

Comment: what about separating the args inside the function being called? or is the function generic too?

Comment: I need to implement retry_till_success(any_method, array(args1, args2, ...))
accept any method with any number of args to execute it till success.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, but this is how call_user_func(_array)() works:

```
call_user_func($method, $arg); //call global function named $method like this: $method($arg)
call_user_func(array($this, $method), $arg); call class method on this class like this: $this->$method($arg);
//lets presume args is an array: $args = array(1, 2);
call_user_func_array($method, $args); //calls global function named $method like this: $method($args[0], $args[1]);
call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $args); //calls class method like this: $this->$method($args[0], $args[1]);
```

Also see the documentation for call_user_func:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php
and for call_user_func_array:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Answer (score 0):

`$this->getCreatives` won't work because in PHP functions are not base class citizen. You can use `call_user_func[_array]` or create a factory for tasks and represent every task as an object which implements an interface (ie iRepeatableTask). Thus you can call

```
try
{    
    $task->repeatUntilSuccess()
} catch (SoapFault $e) {...}
```

and the advantage is that those objecs are easy-to-save/restore in DB to perform later (ie with cronjob etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution I'm using in production.

```
    protected function retry_till_success($method, $args) {
    /*
    *   -1 : unrecoverable error
    *    0 : recoverable error
    *    1 : success
    */
    $success = 0;
    $tries = 0;

    do {
        $tries++;
        $success = call_user_func_array( array($this, $method), $args );
        if ($success===0) {
            usleep(self::DELAY_MS);
        }
    } while ($success===0 && $tries < self::MAX_RETRIES);

    if ($tries >= self::MAX_RETRIES)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```